# access two instances with same code without repeating it for each one

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have two instances named (inst_1 and inst_2) and i want to make operation on  both of them with the same code without repeating the code for each instance.

So how can i make (for loop  or if condition) or anything to do that?
The instance_1 is marked in yellow in the next photo .
I want to change it to instance_2 without repeating code.

here is the image for my code
[image]

Comment: Do not put images of your code in. Put the code itself in.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate over identifier names in Verilog/SystemVerilog. Had you used a `generate-for` loop to instantiate the two instances, you might have been able to use a similar `generate-for` with this code.

The best option I can think of is turning your code into a giant macro, and then calling the macro for each instance.

There are ways of using the PLI/VPI C interface to access identifiers by string lookup, but that is way too involved to get into here.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve what you desire though none of them is good. Verilog is not designed to do it.

1) use what dave_59 suggested: make a huge macro and pass instance name as a parameter. It will work, but you will have issues debugging this monster.

```
`define MONSTER(INST_NAME) ... tb.INST_NAME.....\
    ...tb.INST_NAME...\
    ...

module top1;
`MONSTER(inst_1)
endmodule
module top2;
`MONSTER(inst_2)
endmodule
```

2) define use this piece of code in an include statement, define instance name as a macro:

```
module top1;
`define INSTANCE inst_1
`include "monster_piece.v"
endmodule
module top2;
`define INSTANCE inst_2
`include "monster_piece.v"
endmodule
```

where the monster_piece.v contains your code with `INSTANCE in there. This method has issues with maintenance and some tools might have issues with debugging.

3) the best way is to organize your test bench differently:

- use generate blocks to instantiate your instances in tb, then you can use same in your code.
- you might be able to re-write your TB to use virtual interfaces
  or dynamic classes instead of instances.